What is the trick of integrating $\int\frac{\tan(23x)}{\tan(x)}dx$?
Recently I have seen Syamaprasad Chakrabarti's post and suddenly one question stuck in my mind.
For Syamaprasad's integral there is a closed form summation formula of $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$. But suppose if I give an integral like
$$\int\frac{\tan(23x)}{\tan(x)}dx$$ then I don't think that we can express this integral as a closed form of summation.
Why? Because I know that we can find the summations of $\sin$ and $\cos$ series but not for $\tan$ series.
$\sin(a)+\sin(a+b)+\sin(a+2b)+\sin(a+3b)+...+\sin(a+(n-1)b)=\frac{\sin(\frac{nb}{2})}{\sin(\frac{b}{2})}(\sin(a+(n-1)\frac{b}{2})$
And
$\cos(a)+\cos(a+b)+\cos(a+2b)+\cos(a+3b)+...+\cos(a+(n-1)b)=\frac{\sin(\frac{nb}{2})}{\sin(\frac{b}{2})}(\cos(a+(n-1)\frac{b}{2})$
But There is no summation formula of
$\tan(a)+\tan(a+b)+\tan(a+2b)+...+\tan(a+(n-1)b)$.
Then how to integrate $$\int\frac{\tan(23x)}{\tan(x)}dx$$ ?
Please help me.

May be $\tan(nx) = n \tan(x) + \mathcal{O}(\tan(x)^3)$ helps...

Then, $$\int \frac{\tan(23x)}{\tan(x)} dx = 23x + M(\tan(x) - x) + \mathcal{C}$$ where $\mathcal{O}(\tan(x)^2) = M\tan(x)^2$ for some $M \in \mathbb{Z}$

Have a look at https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/16/04/02/ and use what @Yves Daoust wrote in comments; And, have fun

Where did you find the need to evaluate such an absurd/horrific integral?
